# Server certificate verification failed

Tags: svn

When I execute svn in command line:

```
command: svn commit path -m "Uploaded By  User" --username username 
  --password password  --non-interactive --trust-server-cert  --quiet 2>&1
```

This results in an error:

> Array
>       (
>           [0] => svn: Commit failed (details follow):
>           [1] => svn: OPTIONS of 'svn url': Server certificate verification failed: certificate has expired, issuer is not trusted (svn url :8443)
>       )

Answer (score 8):

The meaning of `--trust-server-cert` has changed, equivalent behaviour is now specified like this:

`svn checkout https://your.repository.url/ --non-interactive --trust-server-cert-failures="unknown-ca,cn-mismatch,expired,not-yet-valid,other" --username=blah --password=blah`

Answer (score 3):

Did you try without `--trust-server-cert` option : it will ask you to accept/reject the certificate.
`--trust-server-cert` option is only available since svn 1.6

Answer (score 3):

Tortoise SVN solution:

I just had this happen to me today running on Windows 7 trying to use svn from git bash.  Any command I used that tried to hit the server would get the same "Server certificate verification failed: certificate has expired, issuer is not trusted".  Usually, just continuing to try to hit the server will cause svn to then ask you if you trust the server.  If you say yes, then all is well.

However, this time, none of that was working.  I finally noticed that the svn I was using was part of the installation of Tortoise SVN.  So I pulled up File Explorer and tried updating my directory through the Tortoise controls.

Tortoise handled everything perfectly.  I got a window asking if I trusted the server.  I said yes permanently.  Then it asked me for my username and password.  After I gave that, Tortoise updated the folder, and when I tried interacting with the server via the command line, that was just fine, too.

Bottom line: If you are on Windows using the command line svn as part of the Tortoise package, try updating directly through the Tortoise controls.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed via console:

```
rm ~/.subversion/auth/svn.ssl.server/*
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using an SSL connection to the web server (ie: your repository path begins with https://) and the certifiacte that is installed on that server has expired.

You will need to contact the server's administrator to get the certificate updated (or use a non-SSL checkout if that suits your security requirements).

Comment: It could be that your graphic client is using a different connection to the repository (or there is a flag set in it to ignore certificate errors).

Answer (score 0):

This just happened to me using the PhpStorm IDE locally with a self-signed certificate on my server, which started reporting "Error:Server SSL certificate rejected" today (it had expired), and i fixed it by going to the terminal and doing "svn update" which replied with:

```
Error validating server certificate for 'https://example.com:443':
 - The certificate is not issued by a trusted authority.
Use the fingerprint to validate the certificate manually!
 - The certificate hostname does not match.
 - The certificate has expired.
Certificate information:
 - Hostname: *.example.com
 - Valid: from Jun  6 13:18:35 2010 GMT until Jun  5 13:18:35 2015 GMT
 - Issuer: (jonny@example.com)
 - Fingerprint: **:**:**:**:**:**:**:**:**:**:**:**:**:etc
(R)eject, accept (t)emporarily or accept (p)ermanently?
```

Replying with "p" updated my trusted certificates and all was well again.

**However** only use this if you really do trust the server, of course!

Hope that helps someone else!

Comment: I need to write a code to automatically run.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue but with Netbeans 8.1  issue was i had an old repository url for cvsdude which is now cloudforge. So all I had to do was got to Team/Working Copy/Relocate and change the old url to the new and that fixed my issues.