# SharpSVN - Server certificate verification failed

Tags: c#, certificate, commit, sharpsvn

I use SharpSVN and I add a folder to the subversion. Then I try to commit it and I get this exception:

`SharpSvn.SvnRepositoryIOException: OPTIONS of 'https://sth.com/svn/blah/Documents': Server certificate verification failed: certificate has expired, certificate issued for a different hostname, issuer is not trusted`

As far as I see here:
[Server certificate verification failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5165516/server-certificate-verification-failed)

..it seems that I must use a `--trust-server-cert` option, but I don't see this anywhere in the arguments of `SvnCommitArgs`.

Also, I have found this:
[How do I use a custom Certificate Authority in SharpSvn without installing the certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11652229/how-do-i-use-a-custom-certificate-authority-in-sharpsvn-without-installing-the-c)

..where I see this:

```
client.Configuration.SetOption(...)
```

But I don't know what settings I must provide to make it commit without problems.

Has anyone done anything similar?

**EDIT**:
I have also tried doing this:

```
client.Authentication.SslServerTrustHandlers += new EventHandler<SharpSvn.Security.SvnSslServerTrustEventArgs>(Authentication_SslServerTrustHandlers);

    void Authentication_SslServerTrustHandlers(object sender, SharpSvn.Security.SvnSslServerTrustEventArgs e)
    {
        // Accept ceritificate here?
    }
```

But I don't understand what I must do inside the handler to accept the certificate... :(

Answer (score 13, accepted):

OK. I solved this problem and now I get an other error.
What you need to do is this:

```
    client.Authentication.SslServerTrustHandlers += new EventHandler<SharpSvn.Security.SvnSslServerTrustEventArgs>(Authentication_SslServerTrustHandlers);
    void Authentication_SslServerTrustHandlers(object sender, SharpSvn.Security.SvnSslServerTrustEventArgs e)
    {
        // Look at the rest of the arguments of E, whether you wish to accept

        // If accept:
        e.AcceptedFailures = e.Failures;
        e.Save = true; // Save acceptance to authentication store
    }
```

Comment: Make sure you also look at the other argument of "E" and check. This allows *all* SSL certs (also expired, revoked etc)